# How to apply double quotes to each value in a comma-space delimited string?

Tags: php, arrays, csv, str-replace, quoting

I want to add double quotes of my every array.

Original value is:

```
192.168.183.2, 192.168.183.28
```

The current result is:

```
"192.168.183.2, 192.168.183.28"
```

What I want is:

```
"192.168.183.2", "192.168.183.28"
```

and here is my code:

```
$allowedIP = array($dScheduler['ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS']);
echo $newarray='"'.implode('","', $allowedIP).'"';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input value is a string, so handle it with just one string function call (`str_replace()`):

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3e567e401de3c6db3e1cd610a4cb374f0ce902f9))

```
$dScheduler['ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS']='192.168.183.2, 192.168.183.28';  // your input string
$wrapped='"'.str_replace(', ','", "',$dScheduler['ALLOWED_IP_ADDRESS']).'"';
echo $wrapped;

echo "\n\n";
// if you want an array:
$array=explode(', ',$wrapped);  // generate result array
foreach($array as $v){
    echo "$v\n";
}
```

The value delimiter in your input string is: `,`, so you just need to change it to `", "` and wrap the entire string in `"` as well.
Then you simply explode on the commas to generate your desired array of elements.

Output:

```
"192.168.183.2", "192.168.183.28"

"192.168.183.2"
"192.168.183.28"
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it through a loop:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $a) {
   $new_array[] = '"'.$a.'"';
}
```

It will create a new array with ", around each element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
<?php
$allowedIP = array('192.168.183.2, 192.168.183.28');

$arrAllowedIP = explode(',', $allowedIP[0]);

$quotedIP = array_map(function($val)
{
    return '"'.trim($val).'"';
}, $arrAllowedIP);
```

Comment: The current condition is $allowedIP = array('192.168.183.2, 192.168.183.28'); any idea?

Comment: Sure, just explode the string on the comma.

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
$arr = ["192.168.183.2", "192.168.183.28"];

$imp = '"'.implode('", "', $arr).'"'; // to string with double quote

$exp = explode(',', $imp); // to array with double quote

echo $im;

print_r($exp);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    $allowedIP = array('192.168.183.2, 192.168.183.28');
    $new= implode($allowedIP);
    $fl=','; 

    foreach (explode(',',$new) as $v){ 
      echo '"'.$v.'"'.$fl; 
           $fl=''; 
        };
```